# Exception from Func<> not caught (async)

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, lambda, async-await

I'm having the following piece of code (simplified in order to make this repro).  Obviously, the catch exception block will contain more logic.

I am having the following piece of code:

```
void Main()
{
    var result = ExecuteAction(async() =>
        {
            // Will contain real async code in production
            throw new ApplicationException("Triggered exception");
        }
    );
}

public virtual TResult ExecuteAction<TResult>(Func<TResult> func, object state = null)
{
    try
    {
        return func();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // This part is never executed !
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception caught with error {ex.Message}");
        return default(TResult);
    }
}
```

Why is the catch exception block never executed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exception is not thrown because the actual signature of func is `Funk<Task>` due to the method being async.

Async methods have special error handling, the exception is not raised until you await the function. If you want to support async methods you need to have a 2nd function that can handle async delegates.

```
void Main()
{
    //This var will be a Task<TResult>
    var resultTask = ExecuteActionAsync(async() => //This will likely not compile because there 
                                                   // is no return type for TResult to be.
        {
            // Will contain real async code in production
            throw new ApplicationException("Triggered exception");
        }
    );
    //I am only using .Result here becuse we are in Main(), 
    // if this had been any other function I would have used await.
    var result = resultTask.Result; 
}

public virtual async TResult ExecuteActionAsync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func, object state = null)
{
    try
    {
        return await func().ConfigureAwait(false); //Now func will raise the exception.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception caught with error {ex.Message}");
        return default(TResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott.  I knew it had to be related to the async behavior.  You nailed it.  It doesn't compile indeed, but that's solved by calling the method like this:     var resultTask = ExecuteActionAsync<string>(....

Comment: @SamVanhoutte being that there is nothing depending on context I threw on a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in the method. It is a good idea to do that wherever possible when working with asnyc/await it makes the program faster (by not waiting for the UI to become available) and reduces the chance for deadlocks if someone else writes bad code and does a `.Result` or `.Wait()` on a UI thread while calling your code. See the article "[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)" for more information.